# How to handle multiple paginations with one link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

In basic pagination we get some next url for loading more data, but if those data have more data with pagination as well, how can I customize and use different parameters for different data:

```
?page=2 to ?posts=2&comments=1
```

And then use one for one, other for other..

I am using api resource with main UserResource which returns posts with PostsResource which uses pagination and returns CommentsResource whicch uses pagination as well.

Comment: the paginate method accepts a ```$pageName``` argument. The method is ```public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)```, so you could do something like ```->paginate(15, '[*]', 'posts)``` and same for comments

Comment: Where can I find these in docs I looked everywhere? :D So basically I can use any link and pass into paginate parameter and page number? something like:

?posts=2&comments=1 
->paginate(15, '[*]', 'posts', $request->query('posts')) for postsResource and same for commentsResource? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the page name in the pagination.

This is un-documented, but the paginate method looks like this:

```
public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null) {
```

So you can set the `pageName` parameter like this:

```
Post::paginate(15, '[*]', 'posts')
Comment::paginate(15, '[*]', 'comments')
```

If you were using blade, it might look like this:

```
$posts->appends(array_except(Request::query(), 'posts'))->links();
$comments->appends(array_except(Request::query(), 'comments'))->links();
```

Considering you are using an api, you could access the current page using the [meta key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#pagination).

eg.

```
posts.meta.current_page
comments.meta.current_page
```

There is also a [setPageName method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/adb72b434903336ff75cc8d21a3026e5835a3be4/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L352) where you can set the `pageName`

eg.

```
$posts = Post::paginate(15);
$posts->setPageName('posts');
```

Comment: Well I said I am using api resources so there is no blade :D Anyway got it to work the way I commented :D

Comment: But you can tell me how to get just next page number not full url? :D oor do I need to explode by = and use second one as number for next page?

Comment: Sorry, Yes, so your json resource pagination response should contain a meta key, where you can access the ```meta.current_page``` value. See here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#pagination

Comment: The problem is I am not using collection because I cannot customize it like resource where I can return into collection. If you know what I mean?
Currently I am getting total number of pages and on front I am checking is loadmore incremented <= to total pages and if it is not or bigger number from total it wont call for more.

Comment: Ok, I am missing something in your resource code then. Anyway, Hopefully, I have helped put you on the right track. :-)

Comment: Yeah, this un-doc info helped me out :D It shouldnt be hard to add these lines to the docs but I cant change their mind :D